# Reduce run time for large number of calculations

Tags: c++, algorithm

Zoom along Waa is a simple game organised by Mathematics Department of SKIT. The goal of the game is to say positive integers in increasing order, with a twist: You don't say the numbers divisible by 3 and 5. Instead, whenever a number was divisible by 3 you say "zoom" and for a number divisible by 5 you say "waa". (Thus, if a number was divisible by 15, you say "zoomwaa".)

Here is how the game starts:

```
1, 2, zoom, 4, waa, zoom, 7, 8, zoom, waa, 11, zoom, 13, 14, zoomwaa,  
16, 17, zoom, 19, waa, zoom, 22, 23, zoom, waa, 26, zoom, 28, 29,  
zoomwaa, 31, 32, zoom, 34, waa, zoom, ...
```

Zoom along Waa has also become a traditional programming question for SKIT's CS students. However, in this problem we have a more tricky assignment for you.

You are given longs A and B. Consider the part of the game that corresponds to integers from A to B, inclusive. During this part of the game, you will say "zoom" X times, "waa" Y times, and "zoomwaa" Z times. You have to determine X, Y and Z.

**Input :**

First line of input contains an integer T, denoting the number of test cases. Each test case have one line of input containing two space separated integers, A and B.

**Output :**

Print the value of X, Y and Z on a single by space separation for each test case.

**Constraints :**

1 <= A <= 10^18
A <= B <= 10^18
1 <= T <= 4

**Sample Input (Plaintext Link)**

```
4
1 4
2 6 
150 165 
474747 747474
```

**Sample Output (Plaintext Link)**

```
1 0 0
2 1 0
4 2 2
72728 36363 18182
```

My code for this is given below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long long num[2];
int t,i,j,ii,jj,kk;
//--t is number of test inputs--//
cin>>t;
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    <!--ii increments if number is divisible by 3 i.e., number is Zoom--
      --jj increments if number is divisible by 5 i.e., number is Waa--
      --kk increments if number is divisible by 15 i.e., number is Zoom-- 
    ii=0;jj=0;kk=0;
    for(j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        cin>>num[j];
    }
    while(num[0]<=num[1])
    {
        if(num[0]%3==0 && num[0]%15!=0)
        ii++;
        if(num[0]%5==0 && num[0]%15!=0)
        jj++;
        if(num[0]%15==0)
        kk++;
        num[0]++;
    }
    cout<<ii<<" "<<jj<<" "<<kk<<endl;
}
cin>>t;
}
```

This code valid for given sample output
it does not works for below given input,i.e.,
**Sample Input**

```
3
1 961574729077486878
1 969690745985575352
2 932572744790738365
```

**Sample Output**

```
256419927753996501 128209963876998250 64104981938499125
258584198929486760 129292099464743380 64646049732371690
248686065277530231 124343032638765116 62171516319382557
```

Please specify a suitable algorithm to reduce runtime of Program...Since 
    while loops takes a lot time in doing calculations.

Comment: You don't need to loop to count numbers divisible by 3 (or 5 or 15).

Comment: As you input is `long long`, output should also be `long long` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't iterate the given range, as that will be too slow.

Let's solve a simpler problem that deals with a range `[1, x]`:

In this range, there are:

```
x / 3 numbers divisible by 3
x / 5 numbers divisible by 5
x / 15 numbers divisible by 15
```

Now you want those divisible by `3` but not by `15`, by `5` and not by `15`, by `15` and you also want to generalize it to a range `[a, b]`. You should be able to do that from here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mathematical shortcut here.  You can use the inclusion-exclusion principle from discrete math to determine the values of X, Y, and Z.  For example, let's go through the concept using the range [10, 100].

For 3: 10/3 = 3 and 100/3 = 33. For 5: 10/5 = 2 and 100/5 = 20. For 15: 10/15 = 0 and 100/15 = 6.

Notice that you must do an int divide always rounding down.

Now, 33-3 = 30, 20-2 = 18, and 6 - 0 = 6.  You know that there will be a value of 6 for Z because there are 6 numbers in this range divisible by 15.  However, the value for Y is NOT 18.  You must consider that 15 is divisible by 5, so you need to subtract out the number Z.  18 - Z(6) = 12.  The same holds true for finding X.  33 - Z(6) = 27.  So, for this example, the answers are X = 27, Y = 12, and Z = 6.

As a general case, here is what you need to do:

Divide the lower bound of the range by each of the factors (3, 5, and 15) and save these values, always rounding down to the nearest integer.  Then divide the upper bound of the range by each of the factors, again rounding down to the nearest integer.  Subtract these values to get the amount of numbers in the range divisible by each of these numbers.  Then remember that some numbers are counting twice, subtracting your values for zoombah from both zoom and bah. This will get you the right answer.

Edit: After reviewing other answers, I realize that you must also check to make sure that your lower bound is not perfectly divisible by the factor.  If this is the case, then you must add 1 to your "number of numbers divisible by X in the range."

Comment: @IVlad Thank you, after reading your comment on the above answer, I have edited my answer to reflect what you have said.  You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can find number of elements divisible by `x` from 1 to n by `n/x`

So to find number of elements divisible by 3 from `a` to `b`(inclusive) by

```
b/3 - a/3
```

But if a is divisible 3 you'll get one less. So decrease `a` by 1

```
a1=b/3 - (a-1)/3;
a2=b/5 - (a-1)/5;
a3=b/15 - (a-1)/15;


// To remove numbers divisible by 3 and 15
a1=a1-a3;
// To remove numbers divisible by 5 and 15
a2=a2-a3;
cout<<a1<<" "<<a2<<" "<<a3<<endl;
```

Comment: You don't need those checks if you do `b / 3 - (a - 1) / 3`